# OpenMP: Call parallelised function from both parallel and serial regions

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a callback function (`inParallel` in the MWE) to iterate over a data structure in parallel. When it was written, it was intended to be called from serial regions. Now, the need arose to call it from within a parallel region as well.

I *could* use a condition inside the function, which checks `omp_in_parallel()`. However, all that really changes between the branches is one line, i.e. the OpenMP clauses change from `parallel for` to `for`. The whole loop is just duplicated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>

static constexpr int nIter { 32 };

template<typename Callable>
void inParallel( Callable&& func ){
    if ( omp_in_parallel() ){
        #pragma omp for
        for ( int i=0; i<nIter; ++i ){
            func(i);
        }
    } else {
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for ( int i=0; i<nIter; ++i ){
            func(i);
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec ){
    for ( const T& t : vec ){
        os << t << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}


int main(){
    std::vector<int> whichThread (nIter);
    
    std::cout << "Outside parallel region:\n";
    inParallel( [&](int i){
        whichThread[i] = omp_get_thread_num();
    } );
    std::cout << whichThread << '\n';

    std::cout << "Inside parallel region:\n";
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        inParallel( [&](int i){
            whichThread[i] = omp_get_thread_num();
        } );
    }
    std::cout << whichThread << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is: is there another way to achieve the same result but without the code duplication? For example, so that OpenMP effectively ignores the 'parallel' clause if in a parallel region? Other solutions that lead to minimal code duplication are equally welcome.

EDIT: I tried `omp_set_nested(true)` before, which lead to a segfault. *That's why I even posted the question.* Now I managed to reproduce it, though the logic is slightly different:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <omp.h>

template<typename Callable>
void inParallel( Callable&& func ){
//  #pragma omp for
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for ( int i=0; i<64; ++i ){
        func(i);
    }
}

int main(){
    omp_set_nested(true);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        std::stringstream s; s
            << "Thread #" << omp_get_thread_num()
            << '\n';
        inParallel( [&](int i){
            s << i << ' ';
        });
        s << '\n';
        for (int i{0}; i<omp_get_num_threads(); ++i){
            #pragma omp barrier
            if ( i == omp_get_thread_num() ){
                std::cout << s.str();
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Using `#pragma omp for` inside `inParallel` works as intended, but `#pragma omp parallel for` leads to a segfault. Leaving out `omp_set_nested(true)` or setting it to false lets each thread go through all iterations (as would be expected).

Answer (score 0):

By default, nested parallelism is not turned on in OpenMP (at least before version 5.0). So if you do this for e.g.:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
     // Some work
  }
}
```

then the inner loop is *not* parallelised, despite the presence of the `#pragma` statement. If it's enabled by setting `OMP_NESTED` to `true`, you can turn it off/on selectively within your code by using `omp_set_nested`

Comment: I had already tried `omp_set_nested(true)` in the MWE, and commenting out the `omp_in_parallel()` branch. It produced a segfault, so I thought it can't work. Now I tried it again, and it appears to work just fine....
It was really the first thing I tried. Well...

Comment: Edited my question to show when the segfault occurs.